# Https in form submit using spring security

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a form of user registration inside a dialog. Because some information of the form is sensitive (personal information and password) I would like to secure the connection just for submitting the form, but I couldn't find anything about securing just a form post.

Anyone knows how to do this?

btw, I'm using spring and spring security

Thanks

Comment: Two things, you need to look into Cross Site Request Forgery and SSL. To secure the connection, you have to use SSL and for CSRF http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html

Comment: Another Spring Security feature that is useful is the HSTS support (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-hsts) - modern browsers can be forced to communicate with your app over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the action of a form to modify the protocol (normal HTML).

But if you are already using Spring Security with session-based security (the default), or even stateless HTTP Basic authentication, you already need SSL for all requests.